# Send push notifications using Registration ID through Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: windows, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-notificationhub, wns

I am trying to use Azure Notification Hubs to send push notifications to a client. I read this article which uses tags to identify each user.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-notify-users/

It does the work, but the number of tags is limited. I was thinking to store and use the Registration ID that the Hub returns.

Is there any way to send notifications using this ID?

Another way would be using the Channel.URI that is returned by WNS. Can this be implemented somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually NH limits only number of tags **per single registration** but per hub you may have as many registrations as you need and each registration may have unique tag which you can use to route the notifications.

Also there is new Installation API for Notification Hubs which I believe fits better for you. It is still not well-documented but well-done and ready to use. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend) you can find short description of how to use that API. Readme is about Java but .NET SDK has pretty much the same capabilities (in the end both call same REST API).

Comment: If you take a look at the tier table (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/), the  # of tags (broadcast groups) is limited to to 3 K. If I got right the first part of your answer, you're telling that this limit is PER USER??? If yes, it is surprisingly high to me.

What I'm trying to do here, is sending push notifications without using tags, but Registration IDs instead. Is that possible?

Comment: PS. Maybe it's not clear enough for me. Tags are part of the NH or the PN Services of each platform?

Comment: Nevermind, I found my solution in your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098667/azure-notification-hub-tag-limits

Answer (score 1):

Keyword is **TAG** ! If you use any spesific tag for any registered device which is Android,IOS,Windows OS etc, you can send notification to any specific device.

To do these, you should follow below steps one by one ;

- As Client side, register device using a spesific tag to selected Azure Notification Hub

> Client Example for Android :

```
`/*you don't have to use Firebase infrastructure. 
  You may use other ways. It doesn't matter.*/`
   String FCM_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
   NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(NotificationSettings.HubName,
                                  NotificationSettings.HubListenConnectionString, context);
   String registrationID = hub.register(FCM_token, "UniqueTagForThisDevice").getRegistrationId();
```

Like you see, we have used a unique tag call `"UniqueTagForThisDevice"` for selected Android device.

- As Server Side, you should send notification using that TAG call  `"UniqueTagForThisDevice"`.

> Server Example using Web API to send push selected Android device :

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("api/sendnotification/{deviceTag}")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> sendNotification(string deviceTag)
  {
      //deviceTag must be "UniqueTagForThisDevice" !!!
      NotificationHubClient Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature>");
      var notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"Hello Push\"}}";
      NotificationOutcome outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif,deviceTag);
      if (outcome != null)
      {
         if (!((outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) ||
            (outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Unknown)))
            {
                return Ok("Push sent successfully.");
            }
      }
      //Push sending is failed.
      return InternalServerError();
  }
```

- As last, you should call above Web API Service method using `"UniqueTagForThisDevice"` tag from any helper platform (Postman, Fiddler or anothers.).

**Note :** **TAG** doesn't have to be deviceToken or similar things. It just have to spesific for each devices. ***But*** I suggest you that, if you use WebAPI and it is related with Owin midlleware, you may prefer username as unique tag. I think, this is more available for application scenarios. In this way, you can carry sending notifications from unique devices to unique users ;)

That's all.