# Azure Notification : meaning of 3K unless broadcasted to less than 5 devices

Tags: azure, notifications, tags, azure-notificationhub

I'm checking how to implement about Azure Notification
But I got this limitation 
"3K unless broadcasted to less than 5 devices"  on this link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/

Can someone help confirm what is meaning of the sentence ?

I found this link but still unable understand the sentence
[azure notification hub tag limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098667/azure-notification-hub-tag-limits)

Answer (score 1):

We have gotten rid of the tag limit associated with tiers. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/ has the latest information. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/ will be updated accordingly shortly as well.